# opendir trying to find paths which don't exist now because they're renamed

Tags: php, error-suppression

I am setting up renaming functionality a part of a crud system for dirs, and right setting up a process to rename sub-directory of an uploads directory and the renaming process is working meaning dirs are being renamed accordingly yet I am getting error codes from
opendir. Apparently the paths are not being found because they're paths that had been renamed. Not sure how to remedy this problem which is the million dollar question??

controller:

```
private function _edify_dirs_recursive($targets, $new_dirs)
{
    $targets = rtrim(preg_replace(array("/\\\\/", "/\/{2,}/"), "/", $targets), "/");
    $new_dirs = rtrim(preg_replace(array("/\\\\/", "/\/{2,}/"), "/", $new_dirs), "/");
    $explode_targets = explode(',',$targets);
    $explode_new_dirs = explode(',',$new_dirs);

    foreach($explode_targets as $target_keys):
        $dirs_obsolete = "./uploads/$target_keys";
        foreach($explode_new_dirs as $new_dirs_keys):
            $dirs_new = "./uploads/$new_dirs_keys";
            $chid_generator = @rename($dirs_obsolete,$dirs_new);
            if($dhandle = @opendir("./uploads/$target_keys"))
            {
                while(FALSE !== ($entry = @readdir($dhandle)))
                {
                    { true; }
                }
                //closedir must be within if logic
                @closedir($dhandle);
            }
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: I'm not following the logic of your `opendir` loop; you are constantly replacing your `readdir` iterator with `$chnm_generator`, which is the boolean result of the `rename()` call, but you actually never use `$entry` at all. It makes no sense.

Comment: if it doesn't utilize $chid_generator how is each $dir being renamed accordingly?

Comment: I removed the scalar variable and left just $chid_generator hence {$chid_generator} and either it way it still works although I will leave out $entry for the sake of less code. However if what you had sai d is the case why does it work or is it a hack? For example in windows when you rmdir any $dirs you must closedir before rmdir which doesn't make sense but nullifies the permission's denied error you will otherwise get repeatedly. Let me know what you think and what do you suggest. Right now I just got {$chid_generator;} However I would like get the openddir and readdir errors to stop.

Comment: also a significant fact the paths that are causing the error are the new paths specified by rename function. right now two errors are being outputted involving opendir. Now of course the paths can't be found yet because they're new paths being created via rename so I am wondering if this errors is a result of the bugy windows environment these folders are within. Nonetheless lanzz million dollar question is how can $entry = $chid_generator in fact work? Also what's causing opendir to generate the two errors I had mentioned.

Comment: ok lanzz I did some more testing. Right now when opendir outputs an error what's shown are the paths replaced by rename. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to accomplish in your `readdir()` loop. The line `$chid_generator = @rename($dirs_obsolete,$dirs_new);` assigns a boolean to `$chid_generator`; then in the `readdir()` loop, you repeatedly evaluate this boolean in a void context, which does nothing (the `$chid_generator;` line in the `while` loop). Do you expect somehow to be invoking the `rename` in the `while` loop? Because that's now how anything in PHP works.

Comment: the folders are being renamed by $chid_generator. You keep saying this can't work this way and I am saying it is working and rename is being invoked and replacing current names of each folders with new names.

Comment: I made an alteration in the code example however $entry = $chid_generator || $chid_generator both work as I had said. Also you need to remember PHP is an incredibly loose language and we're operating in a function with the scalar variables we had discussed.

Comment: here's a link to the php manual page on working with opendir. There's a very similar scenario of logic provided as exemplar using opendir. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php See the example. $file in the example is being declared just as the scalar variable $entry.

Comment: This is the example right out of php manual: $dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}

Comment: `rename($oldname, $newname)` [returns boolean](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php); `$chid_generator = @rename($dirs_obsolete,$dirs_new);` assigns a _boolean_ to `$chid_generator`; that is, `$chid_generator` will be either `true` or `false`, depending on whether the `rename()` call was successful. You seem to be under the impression that `$chid_generator = @rename($dirs_obsolete,$dirs_new);` somehow makes `$chid_generator` into a magical spell that would perform a rename when you evaluate it in void context; this simply is not the case.

Comment: Just for the sake of the demonstration, try to replace `while(FALSE !== ($entry = @readdir($dhandle))) { $chid_generator; }` with `while(FALSE !== ($entry = @readdir($dhandle))) { true; }`. I.e., replace `$chid_generator` with the `true` constant. Run your code again and see if by removing the void evaluation of `$chid_generator` in the loop, it somehow stopped working, since you apparently believe that it is performing some function there.

Comment: $chid_generator = @rename($dirs_obsolete,$dirs_new); is already being accomplished. Before the loop we established such equality.

Comment: So what exactly is your `while(FALSE !== ($entry = @readdir($dhandle)))` loop accomplishing? That's what I've been asking since the beginning.

Comment: oh to respond to one of your statements, it is not belief I am simply going by the output provided and the folders are being renamed every time and I can specify 5 to 10 or more current names to be replaced with new names.

Comment: We're opening the directory upon the function being invoked. Yes it returns boolean however what also occurs when I var_dump is when returning $chid_generator the folders are successfully renamed with replacements. Also to answer you question which I thought I had answered, we're opening the directorie(s), reading and then rename upon the rename being invoked subsequently with respect to the other functions.

Comment: ok lanzz, I also altered the while loop to test if in fact perhaps if logic will produce the same result which it did so that renders the while loop null and void however the while loop follows PHP exemplars via the manual and is common practice. I also tried the code you mentioned. I get the same errors from opendir. Any other ideas? Opendir is trying to essentially open directories which have been replaced. So obviously the directories can't be located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've just renamed `./uploads/$target_keys` to `./uploads/$new_dirs_keys`, you shouldn't be trying to `opendir("./uploads/$target_keys")`, but `opendir("./uploads/$new_dirs_keys")`.

Comment: The scenario though seems really quirky

Comment: I tried this which worked but doesn't that seem quirky:  if($dhandle = opendir("./uploads/$new_dirs_keys"))
       {     
       while(FALSE !== ($entry = @readdir($dhandle))) 

  { true; }

       @closedir($dhandle);

       }

Comment: ok there's a lot of disinformation via this site and similar sites and blogs, and the conclusion is apparently you don't need to utilize opendir and/or readdir to rename any dirs or sub-dirs.